# Problem connecting to an Oracle database with SPRING BOOT (SOAP Service)

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, docker, soap

Good morning, I am new to spring boot, and I am building a SOAP service that allows consulting an ORACLE database (which is in a container), but I am faced with the following error that I cannot solve:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
>   required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be
>   found.
>     - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
>     - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper;
>   SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type
>   org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper
>
> Action:
>
> Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type
>   'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.

[image]
Annex the structure of my code:

[image]

SpringBootSoapApp.java

```
package com.example.conexion.soap_service_example;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBootSoapApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSoapApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Cliente.java

```
package com.example.conexion.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @Column(name="CEDULA")
    private int cedula;
    @Column(name="NOMBRE")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name="APELLIDO")
    private String apellido;
    @Column(name="TIPO_CLIENTE")
    private String tipo_cliente;

    // Getter y Setters
    public int getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }
    public void setCedula(int cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }
    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
    public String getTipo_cliente() {
        return tipo_cliente;
    }
    public void setTipo_cliente(String tipo_cliente) {
        this.tipo_cliente = tipo_cliente;
    }


}
```

ClienteService.java

```
package com.example.conexion.service;
import com.example.conexion.entity.Cliente;
import java.util.List;


public interface ClienteService {

    public Cliente getClienteById(long id);
    public List<Cliente> getAllClientes();
}
```

ClienteRepository.java

```
package com.example.conexion.repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.example.conexion.entity.Cliente;

public interface ClienteRepository extends CrudRepository <Cliente,Integer> {

    public Cliente findById(int cedula);

}
```

ClienteEndpoint.java

```
package com.example.conexion.endpoint;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;
import com.example.conexion.entity.Cliente;
import com.example.conexion.service.ClienteService;

import com.example.conexion.ws.ClienteType;
import com.example.conexion.ws.GetAllClientesRequest;
import com.example.conexion.ws.GetAllClientesResponse;
import com.example.conexion.ws.GetClienteByIdRequest;
import com.example.conexion.ws.GetClienteByIdResponse;

@Endpoint
public class ClienteEndpoint {

    public static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.javaspringclub.com/movies-ws";

    private ClienteService service;

    public ClienteEndpoint() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public ClienteEndpoint(ClienteService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getClienteByIdRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetClienteByIdResponse getMovieById(@RequestPayload GetClienteByIdRequest request) {
        GetClienteByIdResponse response = new GetClienteByIdResponse();
        Cliente clienteEntity = service.getClienteById(request.getClienteCedula());
        ClienteType clienteType = new ClienteType();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(clienteEntity, clienteType);
        response.setClienteType(clienteType);
        return response;

    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getAllMoviesRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetAllClientesResponse getAllMovies(@RequestPayload GetAllClientesRequest request) {
        GetAllClientesResponse response = new GetAllClientesResponse();
        List<ClienteType> clienteTypeList = new ArrayList<ClienteType>();
        List<Cliente> clienteEntityList = service.getAllClientes();
        for (Cliente cliente : clienteEntityList) {
            ClienteType clienteType = new ClienteType();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(cliente, clienteType);
            clienteTypeList.add(clienteType);
        }
        response.getClienteType().addAll(clienteTypeList);

        return response;

    }
```

WebServiceConfig.java

```
package com.example.conexion.config;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;
import com.example.conexion.endpoint.ClienteEndpoint;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

     @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext appContext){
            MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
            servlet.setApplicationContext(appContext);
            servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
            return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
        }

        // localhost:8080/ws/movies.wsdl
        @Bean(name = "clientes")
        public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema schema){
            DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
            wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("ClientesPort");
            wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
            wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace(ClienteEndpoint.NAMESPACE_URI);
            wsdl11Definition.setSchema(schema);
            return wsdl11Definition;
        }

        @Bean
        public XsdSchema moviesSchema(){
            return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("cliente.xsd"));
        }
}
```

cliente.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.javaspringclub.com/movies-ws"
    targetNamespace="http://www.javaspringclub.com/movies-ws"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="getClienteByIdRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="clienteCedula" type="xs:long" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="getClienteByIdResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="clienteType" type="tns:clienteType" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="clienteType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="cedula" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="apellido" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="tipo_cliente" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

 <xs:element name="getAllClientesRequest">
        <xs:complexType/>
    </xs:element>    
    <xs:element name="getAllClientesResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="clienteType" type="tns:clienteType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

application.properties

```
# Oracle settings

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.164.7.203:1521/ORCLPDB1.localdomain
spring.datasource.username=cesar
spring.datasource.password=xxxxx123
spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

spring.main.banner-mode=off

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.conexion</groupId>
  <artifactId>soap-service-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>soap-service-example</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
      </parent> 

      <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                 <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
                 <version>1.0.2</version>
             </dependency>  
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                <version>12.2.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                </dependency>

      </dependencies>

      <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>xjc-schema</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>xjc</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/resources/cliente.xsd</source>
                        </sources>
                        <packageName>com.example.conexion.ws</packageName>
                        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                      <source>1.8</source>
                      <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                  </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <repositories>
            <!-- Repository for ORACLE JDBC Driver -->
            <repository>
                <id>codelds</id>
                <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
            </repository>
                <repository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Remove the line from @EnableAutoConfiguration (exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}), which serves to disable the automatic configuration of DataSource, but throws me another error:

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
>
> Action:
>
> If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the
>   classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a
>   particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are
>   currently active).

I am new to spring boot, and I have searched the web but I have not got any solution, I am guided by the example that follows:
https://www.javaspringclub.com/publish-and-consume-soap-web-services-using-spring-boot-part-1/

You can connect to the database calmly from SQL developer, and even from java

**UPDATE**: correct in the line of spring.datasource.driver-class-name = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, but I still have the same problem

Comment: You need to add a configuration which connects to the database. If you are using application.yml, they are usually present under spring -> datasource

Comment: where do i see that? The database configuration is in the application.properties file, which you publish in the problem description

Comment: It might be caused by the typo in your application.properties:
    spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver The equal sign is missing.

Comment: I still have the same problem after the change

Comment: Can you move the the SpringBootSoapApp.java to base level package level. In your case to `come.example.conexion`. Spring usually does a component scan at the level where the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is present

Comment: Does it mean to take it out of the packages and put it at the level of all the packages? because there is no com.example.conexion package

Comment: Yes, move it to the base package. Just to clear it out everything you see in the package separated is a package itself. `com` is a package, `example` is a package.... Package can have files or packages

Answer (score 0):

I spotted a Typo in your config
The line -> spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Should be -> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: I'm still having the same problem